# DWV: Dirty arm with a tight bend on the end

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

[image: a mock-up of the install]
This is a mock-up of a vanity drain rough-in on a 2-foot "dirty"/trap arm.

Ideally the screw fitting that accepts the trap will sit as close to the wall as possible.

1. Is there any reason for this to be 2"?
2. Can the 90° 1/4 Turn Ell be standard instead of long/sweep? EDIT: I realize that in general, a long sweep is required for horizontal-to-horizontal ells, but I'm hoping there's an exception when the ell is the penultimate fitting on the arm.

Comment: I prefer long sweeps as that sharp bend will create a point for soap and toothpaste to build up, once a clogg developed it is tough and sometimes almost impossible to get a snake through a sharp bend.

Comment: @EdBeal, I and several plumbing codes agree with you in the general case, but with it being right there at the mouth of the arm I feel the snaking problem isn't a problem and I'm hoping my local (California) plumbing code agrees with me on that.

Comment: Aren't most sink drains 1 1/2"?  Can't see a reason for 2" here except maybe to help avoid the water backing up.